# What is the correct type for file input events?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue and have a simple file input with a change listener

```
<script setup lang="ts">
function handleSelectedFiles(event: Event) {
  const fileInputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

  if (!fileInputElement?.files) {
    return;
  }

  // handle files ...
}
</script>

<template>
  <input type="file" @change="handleSelectedFiles"/>
</template>
```

The code works fine but the type-check exits with an error code. I get the error message

> error TS2322: Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type 'Event'.

What is the correct parameter type for the `handleSelectedFiles` function?

*As a sidenote: I just want to upload some files and deal with them so there might be better ways to read the selected files from the input*

---

For reproduction purposes:

- Create a new project via `npm init vue@latest` ( simply select everything )
- Replace the App.vue file with the HTML content posted above
- Run `npm run type-check`, it should pass
- Update the dependency `typescript` to `4.8.4` and `@types/node` to `18.11.0`
- Run the type check again, it should fail now

Comment: Are you looking for ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>?

Comment: then I get `Type '(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'Event'.`

Comment: (i have little vue experience, but from what i know in typescript) that means that the @change is looking to set an *Event*, not a function that takes in an event. That is a bit weird, though. Actually, it seems from another StackOverflow *question*, they use `@change="onChange($event)"`. See if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the change event via the `$event` parameter:

```html
<template>
  <input type="file" @change="handleSelectedFiles($event)"/>
</template>
```

The reason why you got the error was because Vue was trying to pass in an `Event` to a function that takes an event:

```
// what vue was trying to pass in (the type of $event)
const event: Event = { ... }

// what you actually had
const numFunction: ((event: Event) => void) => { console.log(num) }
```

That's why you need to call the function with the local `$event` variable, and that function needs to take in an Event, not a specialized event -- this may require casting on your part if you want more type hints

You can find more info in [Vue's Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers)

Comment: but what is the type of `$event`? If it is `Event` then the code should be identical and then I don't know why it doesn't work. Based on the example from the docs https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#method-handlers

Comment: From your error earlier ago, the type of $event is *Event*. The problem is that you can't assign `Event` to `(event: Event) => void`. One takes in an event, and one is an event. I have elaborated more in my answer.

Comment: would you mind telling me which parameter should `handleSelectedFiles` expect instead?

Comment: From your type error: `not assignable to type 'Event'.`, it's looking for the `Event` type.

Comment: but the function is expecting the `Event` type?

Comment: Vue is expecting you to pass `$event` as a parameter to the handleSelectedFiles function: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers